# GnuWin32 Make fails to run a makefile

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I have a small C++ project, and I'm trying to use the GnuWin32 Make utility to build it. 
This is what my calc.mak file looks like:

```
calc.exe : calc.obj stack_c.obj input_c.obj
    cl calc.obj stack_c.obj input_c.obj

calc.obj : calc.cpp calc.h input.h stackseq.h
    cl -c calc.cpp

stack_c.obj : stack_c.cpp stackseq.h
    cl -c stack_c.cpp

input_c.obj : input_c.cpp input.h
    cl -c input_c.cpp
```

These are the contents of the directory that contains the files:

```
 Directory of G:\dev\c++\cpp_in_action\calc

02/02/2011  04:37 PM    <DIR>          .
02/02/2011  04:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/02/2011  04:13 PM             2,288 calc.cpp
02/02/2011  04:19 PM               294 calc.h
02/02/2011  03:16 PM               266 calc.mak
02/02/2011  01:24 PM               455 input.h
02/02/2011  01:33 PM               551 input_c.cpp
02/02/2011  12:03 PM               641 stackseq.h
02/02/2011  03:02 PM               568 stack_c.cpp
               7 File(s)          5,063 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     805,187,584 bytes free
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
G:\dev\c++\cpp_in_action\calc>make -f calc.mak
cl -c calc.cpp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl -c calc.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [calc.obj] Error 2
```

Any ideas about how I can make this work?

Comment: I have found the solution. The problem was that I copied the make file from a book that teaches me C++, and the author forgot to mention that "cl" is the command calling the compiler. I'm actually using g++, so after I replaced "cl" with "g++" the error was gone.

Comment: LucianU: Please add that as a real answer to your question and accept it: that way it won't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was that I copied the make file from a book that teaches me C++, and the author forgot to mention that "cl" is the command calling the compiler. I'm actually using g++, so after I replaced "cl" with "g++" the error was gone.